# Programmatically Detect whether share drive is on UNIX or Windows OS

Tags: windows, filesystems

I would like to know how I can programmatically detect whether a mapped drive in a Windows environment is on a Linux or a Windows server? I would like to do this from a C# Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273824-file-system-type):

Using System.Management classes...

```
string logDisk= "c:";
string CIMObject = String.Format("win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceId='{0}'", logDisk);
using(ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(CIMObject)) {
    mo.Get();
    Console.WriteLine(mo["FileSystem"]);
}
```

The example was for NTFS/FAT filesystems, but it should work for any filesystem Windows can detect.

Comment: How will a Linux based server (accessed via Samba or similar) show up?